# extract data from CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to array or json

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am using curl and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to get live stream:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($ch, $data) {
        
 echo $data.str_repeat(' ',1024*8);
                     
 return strlen($data);
```

and getting this result:

```
data: {"id":"6we3uupSaAJg7P7RBbw47YvSKIQCG","object":"chunk","created":1679435042,"model":"123456","choices":[{"delta":{"content":" J"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
```

any idea how to get put it to array or valid json and get data from {"content"}?
thanks a lot, spent hours on it, cant make it work.
Thanks a lot again for help

Comment: I have never used that, so I honestly will say something from ignorance, why can't you do `json_decode` or what type of output you get? It should be solvable with basic PHP, nothing fancy, what did you try?

Comment: I did json_decode and its giving me empty result

Comment: But what is the result before you try to `json_decode` it? if you do `dd($result)` or whatever the variable is, what type of data you have in there? If it is a string, what string are you getting back? Are you literally getting a string like this: `data: {"id":"6we3uupSaAJg7P7R............`? Do you really have `data: ` on the result?

Comment: if I do dd(), its giving me exactly this:
"""
data: {"id":"chatcmpl-6weKEbzO1mLtCPiZBRHYgUzXRvsFQ","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1679436054,"model":"gpt-4-0314","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}

 ◀


""" // app\Http\Controllers\TestController.php:198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have to remove `data:`  from it.

I have no idea what you are consuming, but one solution (not the best one) is to always remove the first 6 characters (`data:` ), then you have a valid JSON.

That can be as easy as doing:

```php
$result = substr($result, 5);

$array = json_decode($result);
```

That should work, but have in mind that if `data:`  is not always present in the beginning, you have to either check what you have at the beginnnig of the string, or check the API you are consuming to ask for JSON so `data:`  is not returned

Comment: thank you so much, yeah I made it work this way, I have no idea why I didnt figure it out, maybe tired after whole day of programming, it was pretty simple. thanks a lot again!!

Comment: No worries at all! I am intrigued now why you are getting that response back. What are you consuming? What happens if you add `Accepts: application/json` to your CURL? Will it just return JSON? or is it still returing `data: {xxxx`?

Comment: I have there appliaction/json and same. Its fixed and works like a charm